# http get request with data form -d

Tags: angular

I am trying to convert this below to angular ts code.

`curl -v -k https://localhost/abc/ -H"Content-Type:application/json" -H"Authorization: Bearer token_session_id" -d "{\"name\":\"test_name\"}"`

The above doesn't contain POST flag, so I thought it's a get request. but when I don't know how to attach `"{\"name\":\"test_name\"}"` into my request, unless I use post request.

```
let headers = this.buildHeaders(token);
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('name', 'test');

    return this.http.post<QueryResult>(
        url,
        body,  
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            observe: 'response'
        }
    ).pipe(catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => throwError(error)));
```

The http get method only accepts 2 arguments. 
Does anyone know how to change it to http get request, or is not supported?

Comment: A get can't have a body per the spec...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this:

```
this.http.request(
  'GET',
  url,
  {
    body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    observe: 'response'
  }
);
```

Comment: If it doesn't work so angular won't support this kind of request.